# Multi if statement in class parameters setting

Tags: flutter, dart

I know that in the latest version of dart we can use `if` `else` statements inside the build method. Does anyone know if we can use also `if` `else` statement when we setting class parameters? I know I can do inline statement there but inline is a bit hard to read when there are multiple conditions

```
const int i = 0;
class Person {
 // NewClass n = NewClass(a: i == 0 ? 'a' : 'b'); //<- inline statement working
    NewClass n = NewClass(a: if(i == 0)  'a' else 'b'); //<- if statement doesn't
}

class NewClass {
  final String a;
  const NewClass({this.a});
}
```

**Edit:**

Basically in my case I've got an TextField widget where I set its's type parameter from enum (Type.text, Type.numeric...) According to this parameter I want to set The textField parameters (textCapitalization, maxLength and so on)

Comment: You cant use `i` here as part of parameter because it is not *const*, and it cant be *const*, because it is not **static**. Maybe you should change logic and init `NewClass` variable in constructor

Comment: @KirillMatrosov Sorry for that.. It was just a quick written example. The question remains the same

Comment: @delmin That if else works only with collection types. If your type is `final List<String> a;`  then you can do something like: `NewClass n = NewClass(a: [if(i == 0) 'a' else 'b']);`

Comment: @MidhunMP hmm... that doesn't seems to work in dartpad

Comment: you can define a method and implement your logic there then use the method return value as result.

Comment: @delmin I tried that in dartpad before commenting, what's the error you are getting ?

Comment: why not stick with your ternary operator? seems like we're going backwards. If it's multi, then use switch-case on ```a``` then create the object.

Comment: @delmin This is the whole code, if you want to try out again `const i = 1;
class Person {
  
  NewClass n = NewClass(a: [if(i == 0) 'a' else 'b']); 
}

class NewClass {
  final List<String> a;
  
  const NewClass({this.a});
}
void main() {
  print(Person().n.a);
  
}`

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more about why you need this functionality? Because what you are asking seems not possible (without ternary operator). So if you explain the actual scenario, somebody can suggest a better solution.

Comment: He already said it: "I can do inline statement there but inline is a bit hard to read when there are multiple conditions"

Comment: @LorenzoImperatrice: If he is going to use a const variable then what's the point in checking that in the constructor, it's value won't change right ?

Comment: @MidhunMP I'm pretty sure this is just an example of what he would like to do

Comment: @MidhunMP sorry for not replying.. Yes the above is just an example... Basically in my case I've got an TextField widget where I set its's type parameter from enum (Type.text, Type.numeric...) According to this parameter I want to set The textField parameters (textCapitalization, maxLength and so on) I've just chosen the above code for an example and I know it doesn't make sense however having option to use `if` `else` in setting parameters would make my code much more readable.

Comment: @MidhunMP Now I see what you have done there... Yes... Making a list of Strings from String fix the issue however as from above comment I can't use list in TexfField widget maxLength parameter

Comment: @delmin: I've a solution for that. Will add that as an answer. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your comment, you are already creating an enum for specifying the type of the fields.

```
enum Type {text, numeric}
```

Now for specifying the properties of that particular type, you can add an extension on this enum, as shown below:

```
extension TextFieldProperties on Type {
  int get maxLength {
    if (this == Type.text) {
      return 10;
    }
    return 12;
  }
}
```

So in your field class you already have a type defined, you can use that type variable to get the properties of that particular type of field.

```
Type type = Type.text;
print(type.maxLength); // Will print 10
type = Type.numeric;
print(type.maxLength); // Will print 12
```

**Note:** It will work only in Dart 2.7 and above

Comment: Hmm... that looks promising... let me try it and I let you know

Comment: I got it... yes that works and it makes my widget much readable now. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You want the conditional expression (`?:`), not the conditional statement or literal entry (`if`), as you have already discovered.

The reason `if` doesn't work is that `if` only works as a *statement* or as a collection literal *entry*. It doesn't work in arbitrary expressions.
The reason for the distinction is that the `if` syntax allows you to omit the `else` branch. That only makes sense in places where "nothing" is a valid alternative. For a statement, "doing nothing" is fine. For a collection, "adding nothing" is also fine.

In an expression context, you *must* evaluate to a value or throw. There is no reasonable default that we can use instead of "nothing", so an `if` is not allowed instead of an expression.

Comment: Thanks... That is very good explained and it makes sense as well..

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work because this syntax doesn't exist in Dart. The only way to do what you would like to do is to use the ternary operator.

If you try it in the DartPad you will get an error.

I suggest you to use a function to return the right value.

Comment: using function is known way how to do this things. For now I'm using inline statement in my case but it makes the code spaghetti therefore I was hoping for `if` `else` statement. Also making function for each parameters wouldn't make things any better